# Constructing BigInteger at Runtime vs CompileTime

Tags: java

I was wondering which one is better and why ?

```
myFunction(new BigInteger(String1));
```

or

```
BigInteger bigInt = new BigInteger(String1);
myFunction(bigInt);
```

IMO, latter is better since it is not at runtime and we can have bigint during compilation while with the first approach we leave everything up to runtime ?

Pls. correct/update

Comment: What makes you think it happens at compile-time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real difference between these two pieces of code.  The `BigInteger` will be created at runtime in both cases, because it's not a constant expression; the `new` operator will create the object at runtime.

The only possible difference is that the first code example won't have a reference to the `BigInteger` that is created after `myFunction` completes, but the second code example will still have the `bigInt` reference variable.

Comment: Thanks, If for implementation we do not have any differences, which one would you prefer if you are writing clean code ?

Comment: If I knew that I didn't need the `BigInteger` after the call to `myFunction`, then I would use the first one, else I would use the second one.  It's not a big deal either way, because one form is easily convertible to the other form.